# Calling an external function from pari/gp

Tags: pari, pari-gp

Is it possible to call the primesieve (Kim Walisch tool), from the pari/gp and pass the value in a variable in pari/gp? I would like to replace the primePi () function with this (as external function, maybe with system("f") command), because the premisieve is much faster to find prime numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried interfacing with primesieve, but you can definitely use the `system` function to call external programs. The details will vary slightly depending on what operating system you have.

On Windows:

```
 system(Str("echo ", 17, ">c:/work/temp.txt"))
```

will call the `echo` command passing it a value of 17 and writing the output to a temporary file. (Note that I am using forward slash (/) in the path, rather than Windows normal backslash (\) because a backslash is also PARI's string escape character.

Then to read the result back into PARI:

```
read("c:/work/temp.txt")
```

seems to do the trick.

Comment: You can also use `externstr`.